# Display grid is stretching the height of the children elements to fill the screen when their is no new data

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, css-grid

I'm working with display grid in my app. If the data doesn't fill the grid, the items are square - which is how I want it to work. However, when there are enough rows and columns to reach the data length, the grid items become vertically stretched to fill 100% of the component height.
I've looked into this problem and I can't figure it out. I tried adding `padding-top: 100%` to the child divs that the grid is positioning. I've also tried applying `aspect-ratio: 1/1` to the child divs. Neither of these worked.

I'll share my code for this part of the app below, if anyone could help, I'd really appreciate it.

Styled component containing `display: grid`:

```
const StyledAlbums = styled.div`
  height: calc(100% - 5rem);
  width: calc(100% - 8rem);
  margin: 1rem 4rem;
  h3 {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }

  // grid things
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(14rem, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 8rem;
  grid-row-gap: 8rem;
```

Child div `display: grid` is positioning

```
const StyledRecord = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  img {
    border-radius: 1rem;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

// this is positioned below the div
  h3 {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.63%;
    color: ${(props) => (props.theme === "light" ? "#343434" : "white")};
  }
`;
```

JSX returning the parent and children elements

```
  return (
<StyledAlbums
  screenHeight={screenHeight}
  screenWidth={screenWidth}
  rowCountOne={rowCountOne}
  rowCount={rowCount}
  ref={albumsRef}
>
  {albumData.map((album) => (
    <Record
      key={album.id}
      mainImg={album.album_photo}
      title={album.album_name}
    />
  ))}
</StyledAlbums>
);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the defined height, and this fixed it!